# Creating a custom cocos2d/box2d object

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, box2d

I'm trying to create a custom cocos2d and box2d object comprised of multiple bodies and need I little help with the structure.

I want the object to be composed of two bodies and one sprite. This is the header file I have created:

```
@interface NewBlock : CCNode {
    CCSprite *sprite;
    b2Body *body1;
    b2Body *body2;
    b2World *world;
}
```

So I'm inheriting from CCNode which I assume is the correct thing to do. Here is my implementation method:

```
-(id)initWithWorld:(b2World*)theWorld atLocation:(CGPoint)location {
  if (self = [super init]) {

    sprite = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"level_2.png"];

    ...box2d stuff...

    [self addChild:sprite];
  }   
return self;
}
```

And in the scene I want the object, i would create it like:

```
NewBlock *block = [[NewBlock alloc] initWithWorld:world atLocation:ccp(100,100)];
[self addChild:block];
```

I know I could inherit from `CCSprite` but I might want to add more sprites to the object at some point so a more general example would be useful to me.

I have tried an example with the code above and get the following message in the console:

```
sharedlibrary apply-load-rules all
Current language:  auto; currently c++
```

Is my structure for creating a custom cococs2d/box2d object correct? Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The design is good. Personally I favor subclassing CCNode too, for the exact same reason: you never know when your CCSprite needs to contain multiple CCSprite. Thus the CCNode class becomes the controller, and CCSprite and other classes are treated as the View. The b2Body would be the model in this case.

Your error is unrelated to how you designed the class. Does the code still work, or does it crash? Maybe it's one of the many messages that can be ignored.

The usual caveats apply when adding Box2D code. All your classes should use the .mm extension, even those which may not be using Box2D code directly.

Comment: It was an error with my box2d code :) I think you deserve the points as confirmation of a correct design often helps to then identify the error. Creating a class like this allows for some powerful design options!